# Export MS Access query results to CSV programmatically

Tags: ms-access

Working on an old Access 2000 database, and am really rusty. Remembering why I quit doing most Access development a while back, too.  ; )

I have a query that I need to export the results of to a CSV file, and save where the client requests (dialog box). Did some searching on same, but not finding what I need and am back against the wall on time. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Big thanks in advance if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`API for Windows Dialog`](http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm) and the [`TransferText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220768%28office.11%29.aspx) method of the DoCmd object.